# JPA date truncation group by using POSTGRES and eclipselink

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, eclipselink

I am trying to truncate a date, and group by the values.
I have tried this:

#### JPA

```
select v.sop, FUNC('DATE_TRUNC', 'day', v.scrappedAt) as dt, sum(v.totalValue) 
from TABLE v 
where v.coordStatus like 'done%' and (:plant is null or v.target = 
:plant) and v.scrappedAt is not null 
group by v.sop, dt
```

I have also tried grouping by the `FUNC`

```
select v.sop, FUNC('DATE_TRUNC', 'day', v.scrappedAt) as dt, sum(v.totalValue) 
from TABLE v 
where v.coordStatus like 'done%' and (:plant is null or v.target = 
:plant) and v.scrappedAt is not null 
group by v.sop, FUNC('DATE_TRUNC', 'day', v.scrappedAt)
```

The error is the same

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: 
>       ERROR: column "t_mcp_verschrottungs_db_sharepoint.scrappedat" 
>       must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: why not post the actual SQL invoked?!

Comment: @BillyFrost if I write it as a native sql query it works just fine, I was trying to get the JPA working, I have fallen back to native sql already, but am keen to see if it's solvable using JPA - not looking promising though.

Comment: Yes, but the whole point of debugging is to work out why. And if you post what the SQL that is INVOKED then maybe, just maybe there is something

Comment: put another way, show the SQL EclipseLink is generating for you so we can see what is going wrong.  See https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging to turn on logging if it isn't showing up in the error itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, if `FUNC` were a native Postgres function, then your query should be working, and the query would be ANSI compliant.  After reading [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48994080/group-by-trunced-date-in-jpa), it appears that Postgres can't figure out that the two `FUNC` calls are actually the same thing.  Perhaps you can rephrase the sum using a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT
    v1.sop,
    FUNC('DATE_TRUNC', 'day', v1.scrappedAt) AS dt,
    (SELECT SUM(totalValue) FROM TABLE v2
     WHERE v2.sop = v1.sop AND
         FUNC('DATE_TRUNC', 'day', v2.scrappedAt) =
         FUNC('DATE_TRUNC', 'day', v1.scrappedAt) AND
         v2.acoordStatus LIKE 'done%' AND
         (:plant is null OR v2.target = :plant) AND
         v2.scrappedAt IS NOT NULL) value_sum
FROM TABLE v1
WHERE
    v1.coordStatus LIKE 'done%' AND
    (:plant is null OR v1.target = :plant) AND
    v1.scrappedAt IS NOT NULL;
```

An alternative to the above, should it either not work or not be performant, would be to use a native Postgres query.

Comment: this was a great idea, but unfortunately you cannot seem to nest queries in this way in JPA, the nesting has to be an a where clause. Perhaps it's not possible, and I must just use a native SQL query.

Comment: @Jim Is it possible to have a correlated subquery in the `SELECT` clause?  This would be one alternative to using `GROUP BY`.