# Springboot Hibernate & JPA and Native Queries (Group by PostgreSQL date_trunc) pageable problem

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am getting stuck with this JPA query in SpringBoot 1.4.7. The thing is that I get this error while trying to process a Native Query. I have tested the SQL queries and are both valid.

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Could not locate named parameter [signals], expecting one of [toDate, from, device]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate named parameter [signals], expecting one of [toDate, from, device]
```

The query is defined by:

```
    @Query(value = "select device, signal, avg(avg), min(min), max(max), date_trunc('day', timestamp) as timestamp from  devicestatistics d "
            + "where timestamp between :from and :toDate and device like :device and signal IN (:signals) "
            + "group by d.device ,d.signal ,date_trunc('day' , d.timestamp ) order by device,date_trunc('day' ,d.timestamp) Desc \\n-- #pageable\\n",
            countQuery = "SELECT count(1) as NumRows from "
                    + "(select device, signal, avg(avg), min(min), max(max), date_trunc('day', :from) as timestamp from  devicestatistics d "
                    + "where 'time' between :from and :toDate and device like :device  "
                    + "group by device ,signal ,date_trunc('day' ,d.time ) order by device , date_trunc('day' ,d.time ), signal x"
            ,nativeQuery =  true)
    Page<DeviceStatistics> getDataDay(@Param("from") Date from, @Param("toDate") Date toDate, @Param("device") String device, @Param("signals") Collection<String> signals,Pageable page);
```

The table is the following (I know that the names are not chosen wisely).

```
CREATE TABLE public.devicestatistics (
    device text NOT NULL,
    "TIMESTAMP" timestamp NOT NULL,
    signal text NOT NULL,
    avg float8 NULL,
    max int8 NULL,
    min int8 NULL,
    CONSTRAINT devicestatistics_pkey PRIMARY KEY (device, "TIMESTAMP", signal)
);
```

And the entity is defined by:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "DEVICESTATISTICS")
@IdClass(DeviceStatisticsID.class)
public class DeviceStatistics implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "DEVICE")
    private String device;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "SIGNAL")
    private String signal;

    @Column(name = "AVG")
    private double average;

    @Column(name = "MIN")
    private double minimun;

    @Column(name = "MAX")
    private double maximun;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "TIMESTAMP")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date time;
```

Any hints?

The question is similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48994080/group-by-trunced-date-in-jpa) but I was hoping to use the native queries function.

Thanks!

Edit:

If I stop using Pageable it works, however I have not being able to make it work using Pageable... (I have been searching in stackoverflow for solutions but none work)

```
    @Query(value = "select device, signal, avg(avg), min(min), max(max), date_trunc('day', timestamp) as timestamp from  devicestatistics d "
            + "where timestamp between :from and :toDate and device like :device and signal IN (:signals) "
            + "group by d.device ,d.signal ,date_trunc('day' , d.timestamp ) order by device,date_trunc('day' ,d.timestamp) Desc",
            countQuery = "SELECT count(1) as NumRows from "
                    + "(select device, signal, avg(avg), min(min), max(max), date_trunc('day', :from) as timestamp from  devicestatistics d "
                    + "where 'time' between :from and :toDate and device like :device  "
                    + "group by device ,signal ,date_trunc('day' ,d.time ) order by device , date_trunc('day' ,d.time ), signal x"
            ,nativeQuery =  true)
    List<DeviceStatistics> getDataDay(@Param("from") Date from, @Param("toDate") Date toDate, @Param("device") String device, @Param("signals") Collection<String> signals);
```

Comment: I see you have IDClass as DeviceStatisticsID. I assume that class has the three Id columns you have set in this class. If so then this DeviceStatistics should not also have those same Id columns. Instead it should have Id DeviceStatistics deviceStatistics

Comment: Thanks for the tip, however If I change to that approach the error is exactly the same and moreover it breaks the named queries (e.g. findByDeviceAnd....)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it. If someone need to make this kind of Native Queries with grouping this could be helpful.

```
   @Query(value = "select device, signal, avg(avg), min(min), max(max), date_trunc('day', timestamp) as timestamp from  devicestatistics d "
            + "where timestamp between :from and :toDate and device like :device and signal IN (:signals) "
            + "group by d.device ,d.signal ,date_trunc('day' , d.timestamp ) order by device,date_trunc('day' ,d.timestamp) Desc --#pageable\n" ,
            countQuery = "SELECT count(1) as NumRows from "
                    + "(select device, signal, avg(avg), min(min), max(max), date_trunc('day', timestamp) as timestamp from  devicestatistics d "
                    + "where timestamp between :from and :toDate and device like :device and signal IN (:signals) "
                    + "group by device ,signal ,date_trunc('day' ,d.timestamp ) order by device , date_trunc('day' ,d.timestamp ) Desc) x"
            ,nativeQuery =  true)
    Page<DeviceStatistics> getDataDayIn(@Param("from") Date from, @Param("toDate") Date toDate, @Param("device") String device, @Param("signals") Collection<String> signals, Pageable page);
```